# What is the benefit of wrapping a jquery function in a closure?

Tags: jquery

Hi I've been busy trying to take my knowledge of JQuery to the next level, So far I think I've understood everything but as I've ventured onto more advanced tutorials I've noticed several instances where the JQuery routine is wrapped in a closure (see below) however, the thing that confuses me is that it passes a $ and returns JQuery. My question is why? what can I do with the returned JQuery?

I'd really appreciate any light that people can shed on this for me.

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var arr = $.map($("LI"), function(item, index){
      while (index < 3)
      {
        return $(item).html();
      }
      return null;
    });
    $(document.body).append("<span>The first three authors are: " +
      arr.join(", ") + "</span>");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Thank you in advance.

Rob

Comment: Where is jQuery *returned*? I cannot see it. Can you please be more specific? And also `$` is never passed.

Comment: Looking at it now I can see that my question was pooly phrased. I now understand that the self invoking function takes the parameter $ which is passed the argument of the global jQuery object.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235163/what-is-benefit-of-using-function-in-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/631187/javascript-scope-and-closure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a self invoking anonymous function (an un-named function that is declared and immediately executed) that takes one argument that gets assigned to the parameter `$`. The value passed in for the argument is `jQuery`, the jQuery function.

This is done so that the shorthand `$` can be used inside the scope of the function to mean jQuery. Since all of the code inside of the function is in the scope of the function, it's a nice pattern for self containing the code and not polluting the global namespace.

It's also a nice pattern for allowing you to use the `$` shorthand for jQuery inside of the function - it could be the case that the `$` shorthand (`window.$`) is assigned something else, as can happen if you use multiple libraries on one page. By using the pattern, you can still use `$` to reference `jQuery` object in the function for familiarity and terseness.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to reply to my question. Brilliant!

Comment: I can also be an advantage towards javascript minimization. You could pass more global variables towards the function: `(function(doc, win, $, SE){  ...  })(window, document, jQuery, SomethingElse);`. Inside the function the `doc`, `win` and other variable names will be shortened to only one character by most optimizers.

Answer (score 5):

If you are writing a plugin, use

```
(function($) {
  //stuff that uses the jquery lib using $
})(jQuery);
```

This is equivalent to

```
var __myf = function($) {
  //stuff that uses the jquery lib using $
};
__myf(jQuery);
```

If you are writing page code, use

```
jQuery(function($) {
  //stuff that uses the jquery lib using $
});
```

Here, jQuery will invoke your function when it's ready to (when the document is loaded), and will pass itself as the first argument to your function.

Comment: Many thanks for taking the time to reply. Between all of the answers I've recieved to my question I now fully understand what is going on and more importantly why.

Answer (score 1):

This maps jQuery to $ for the scope of the closure, preventing conflicts with other libraries which may also claim the $ namespace (e.g. MooTools).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply to my question. you've really helped my further my knowledge.