# Can I use Ajax submit requests inside a (function($){...}(jQuery));?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, anonymous-function

I'm a PHP developer and know a little bit of javascript. I am using ajax to submit a request to the server. I've read that it's good to put all your code inside the javascript anonymous function like: `(function($){ //code here }(jQuery))`. So, I've put my ajax code inside the anonymous function as well. It's working absolutely fine, but, I'm curious if it's okay to do so or not?

P.s: By **all your code**, I mean the whole `.js` file of the app containing user defined scripts.

Here's an example of my question.

### HTML:

```
<form action="https://www.server-url.com/" method="POST" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="user-name">
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

### JavaScript:

```
(function($){
    var main = {
        serverRequest: ()=>{
            $('#form').submit((e)=>{
                e.preventDefault();

                var username= $('input[name=user_name]').val();

                $.ajax({
                    url: $('#form').attr('action'),
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        user_name: username
                    },
                    success: (res)=>{
                        // success code here...
                    },
                    error: (err)=>{
                        // error code here...
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };

    $(document).ready(()=>{
        main.serverRequest();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Any help would be appreciated, **thanks** in advance. :)

Comment: Your complete code can be written like this if you do not need the IIFE: `$(function() {
  $('#form').on("submit",(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var username = $('input[name=user_name]').val();
    $.ajax({
      url: $('#form').attr('action'),
      type: 'POST',
      data: {
        user_name: username
      },
      success: (res) => {
        // success code here...
      },
      error: (err) => {
        // error code here...
      }
    });
  });
});`

Comment: @mplungjan yeah I know about it. I am just using this approach so that I can format my code better. Instead of making a separate `.js` file and a class, I can manage it in one file very easily under different names. `var main = { request1: ()=>{ // some code; }, request2: ()=>{ // some code; } };`

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a good practice, as it prevents your code getting in conflict with other libraries that might use the $-sign in their own context.

if you are interested, you could take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3579643/what-is-the-benefit-of-wrapping-a-jquery-function-in-a-closure), where your question has already been answered.

Comment: I know about anonymous functions of javascript. My question is, is it okay to use the ajax submit requests in anonymous functions? It was the title of my question. :)