# element = $(element); Object expected error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xhtml, prototypejs

on a webpage in under developmnt i'm getting this error on IE

```
element = $(element);
```

this code is in prototype.js

Object expected

How to get rid of this error.

**Update:**

jQuery is also being used on site.

Comment: Please give more details ,then only i can get you well.

Comment: What is `element` before this line?

Comment: I'm 99% sure (until you post more code) that your $(element) is either undefined, or you're setting some unsupported value.

Comment: @Adam Kiss: that's what it is.

Comment: @Sarfraz: I'm not sure I know what you mean :?

Answer (score 3):

Is "element" the id of your element?  If so try making it `element = $("element")`

Answer (score 2):

your statement should be

```
element = $("id of element")
```

suppose you have the following code.

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  ...
</div>
```

To access this control, in prototype, it is

```
element = $("mainDiv");
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comment, you can combine both jquery and prototype in the same page.

```
var J = jQuery.noConflict();
```

After this statement, $("#foo") will be J("#foo").

See [**this stackoverflow question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134572/jquery-prototype-conflict/136502#136502)

Comment: jquery is also being used on site can this could be a issue

Answer (score 1):

You need to put a var in front of the variable assignment when the variable and element id are the same in IE.

```
var element = $(element);
```