# Conflicts when using both jquery and prototype based components on the same webapge

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, prototypejs, conflict

I need to use UI components based on Jquery and prototype on same webpage. But this leading to conflicts and none of two components(one Jquery slideshow & another prototype based ticker), work normal.

How do I prevent this conflict and make both working together on same php page.

Comment: What conflict would this be exactly? If it has something to do with the jquery `$`, than you should have a look at the API -> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries might be of some use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Jquery noConflict method so that jquery's control of $ variable can be relinquished . Please refer to the below link

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [jQuery.noConflict(); method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

Search before you ask a question though, I just googled and found [a ton of similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134572/jquery-prototype-conflict).

Answer (score 0):

You can always alias jQuery in a self executing method if you need to:

```
 (function($)
 {
      // $ refers to jQuery
 })(jQuery);
```