# Wordpress 3.2.1 javascript error - $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm receiving a $ is not a function error. This is new since I updated from 3.2.1.

I have an identical setup working on 3.1.

Have folks run into this issue? I have turned off all plugins and am just attempting to load the superfish (or any jquery) and am receiving this error.

What changed that I'm missing? These are all currently on the same server if that is any help.

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*EDIT*

*I had the same error, and it was because of jQuery not loaded.*

*You can this error if* your jquery is not loading. *To determine if this is the case,* you need to debug your webpage *network traffic* using IE9 -> F12 -> Network -> Capture to see if you get 404 for jQuery files (i.e. something/wp-includes/jquery.js), or use same thing in Firefox's Firebug extension.

You can also search for jquery in page source, it should be in  tag, and when you find src (i.e. http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js) try open it, if it says 404 not found then you need to place jquery in that file on server (or change whatever php/plugin loads that script tag to correct path)

If you do not know how to do this, please provide link to your wordpress installation.

Comment: This is not necessarily the case. Some setups don't allow you the use the $ alias, such as Drupal 7.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but this is Wordpress not Drupal, and I had same error on my wordpress blog 2 nights ago - wrong path to jQuery.

Comment: +1 Ok. You should include that in your answer -- it would make it more specific & therefore relevant.

Comment: Thanks, it does make my answer better, as it does not have to be the case, but he did not provide link to his wordpress installation.

Comment: The issue was jQuery was improperly linked in theme. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

What happens if you change `$` to `jQuery`? Does that work? `$` is simply a variable for the `jQuery` object. In some setups, you need to use `jQuery` rather than `$`.

Comment: Also, you should use it in the ["noConflict"-mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134572/jquery-prototype-conflict).