# How Do I Solve This JavaScript Conflict Between Prototype And jQuery?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, conflict

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery & Prototype Conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134572/jquery-prototype-conflict)

I think I have a problem between jQuery and prototype the problem only shows in Internet Explorer 8

http://www.urbanclothing.dk/faq/

In IE8 the browser will not expand the faq questions. Can anybody tell me how to solve it?

I'm using the [IEtester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) to test the website with IE8.

Looking forward to get some suggestions.

Comment: look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: @Niels: If you can elaborate a bit more on that I'd consider that a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

`var j = jQuery.noConflict();`

Before you load the prototype library

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.urbanclothing.dk/js/mw_js/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> 
    var j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.urbanclothing.dk/js/prototype/prototype.js"></script>
```

Comment: Okay so I just need to reorder my javascripts?

Because I can see I do have the " var = jQuery.."

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>

Comment: Correct, `noConflict()` doesn't work right when you call it after both jQuery and Prototype have both loaded on the page, you need to load jQuery first, then call `noConflict()`, and finally load prototype.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the $.noConflict you can use multiple libraries

Example

```
$.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
});
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

More info can be found on: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

The $.noConflict() also returns a jQuery object that can be used for jQuery only, or just use `jQuery("")` instead of `$()`

Comment: I have some jquery noConflict in my header: