# jQuery and prototype.js conflict, how to keep jQuery as $?

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

So I'm working on a website that uses both jQuery and prototype.js, however their conflicting.

I've researched a fair bit and found that the only way people fix this issue is by using

```
<script>
 jQuery.noConflict();

 // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(\"div\").hide();
 });

 // Use Prototype with $(...), etc.
 $('someid').hide();
```

However I don't want to change $ to jQuery as that means I'd have to edit a fair bit of pre written code. Is there a way to stop them conflicting and leave jQuery as $?

Comment: Are you asking if you could have, in the same scope, $ mean two different things?

Comment: He's asking if there's a Prototype version of `noConflict()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery & Prototype Conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134572/jquery-prototype-conflict)

Comment: If all of your jQuery is inside of a `$(document).ready(function(){`, you could use `jQuery(document).ready(function($){` and safely use `$` inside of it.

Comment: Why not eliminate one of the libraries? A programmer shouldn't need both. That said, change `jQuery(document).ready(function(){` to `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`, and you're set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of using document ready you can create a closure (at the end of the `body`) like:

```
(function($) {
  //jQuery stuff
  $('.elem') // $ refers to jQuery
})(jQuery);
```

If I understand your question correctly

Comment: Decided to go with this, however annoyingly prototype.js is showing an error now..

Comment: I don't know what @Elliot's original comment was, but I don't see how your IIFE is a replacement for jQuery's `.ready()`. And saying: *"Instead of using document ready you can create a closure..."* doesn't really make sense. The `.ready()` callback is no less of a closure than what you have.

Answer (score 6):

Nope, not that I've heard of. To minimize code conversion pain you could do something like this though:

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

You could then replace jQuery `$` calls with `j$`. You could probably even use a simple search/replace call.

Comment: I think this caused global and local variable issue so decided to go with one above, thanks tho!

Answer (score 2):

```
( function($){
   // $('jquery here')
})(jQuery);
```

All jquery code inside the function can use `$`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do this by wrapping your allready written code into a function and pass jQuery into it. That way you can keep your allready written code and use jQuery as identifier only for the new one:

```
(my_old_stuff = function($){
   $.my_existing_function(){
       alert('i allready exist');
   };
)(jQuery);

jQuery.my_existing_function();
```

That should work.

On the other hand: replacing $ with jQuery doesn't seem to be that much of a task for automatic replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's quite an old post but I exactly had the same problem scenario.
There are a lot of options available to handle it. I wouldn't touch the pre-written code and let prototype js use $.

From the [jQuery documentation](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

```
<!-- Loading jQuery before other libraries. -->
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script>

// Use full jQuery function name to reference jQuery.
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "div" ).hide();
});

// Use the $ variable as defined in prototype.js
window.onload = function() {
    var mainDiv = $( "main" );
};

</script>
```

Here are all the options available.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/