# using Prototype.js with SugarCRM causes menu to dissolve

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, sugarcrm

I am including prototype.js in my tpl file and it is causing error as follows

`TypeError: $("#dcmenu") is null`

When I comment out the prototype.js file the menu is working well. Since i need this file to declare some classes and sugarCRM includes some javascript libraries and Jquery by default how can these two work parallel without conflicting. Jquery's `noConflict()` will not be useful since other pages does not include the prototype file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think prototype.js has the same noConflict option like jQuery has, per other discussions like this...

[jQuery and prototype.js conflict, how to keep jQuery as $?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10034991/jquery-and-prototype-js-conflict-how-to-keep-jquery-as)

Any reason why you need to use prototype.js?

Comment: Ohh it was used in a Module that we created way back and now we are Loading that module in the Newer version of sugar and since sugar includes jquery now, so our prototype is conflicting.